# Dodirectpayment api for recurring subscription

Tags: paypal

This is the url i'm firing =>
         https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?&METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile&USER=xxxxxxxxxx&PWD=xxxxxxxxx&SIGNATURE=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&VERSION=85.0&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&IPADDRESS=203.196.159.36&CREDITCARDTYPE=Discover&ACCT=6011746396125231&EXPDATE=062015&CVV2=456&FIRSTNAME=Tester&LASTNAME=Testerson&STREET=707+W.+Bay+Drive&CITY=Largo&STATE=FL&COUNTRYCODE=US&ZIP=33770&AMT=100.00&CURRENCYCODE=USD&DESC=Testing+recur+Payments+Pro&PROFILESTARTDATE=2014-06-23T17%3A19%3A04%2B05%3A30&BILLINGPERIOD=Day&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1

using this api i'm creating recuring subscription , and the response that was returned
       =>        Array
       (
       [PROFILEID] => I-6X6FYA15LASE
       [PROFILESTATUS] => ActiveProfile
       [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-06-23T11:49:13Z
       [CORRELATIONID] => ce1cf95f1e6e6
        [ACK] => Success
        [VERSION] => 85.0
       [BUILD] => 11457922
       ),
I don't get transactionid , i want to know how to get transaction id from response , also how to  define or pass notify url with this api , please help me , i will be greatful to you then .

Comment: The answer below is correct. Note that if you do NOT charge an initial amount, Paypal will create a profile for you even if the card doesn't work. So, you don't find out about getting a bad card number until the first recurring payment attempt is made, which could be a month after the fact. For this reason, it makes sense to always bill an initial amount -- if that fails, **you still must manually cancel the recurring payment profile**. Also, you won't get very detailed information about the initial payment if it fails. You'll get a transaction ID if it works, or none if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Recurring payments will have to use the default IPN URL configured under https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify

As per the documentation under https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/ you can pass an "INITAMT" variable in order to charge the buyer upon profile creation - that will spawn a txn id.

The ID  I-6X6FYA15LASE is basically the Recurring Payments Profile ID (storing the frequency and terms of the billing) based on the information in the profile ID, PayPal will automatically create transactions between you and the buyer.